# Существуют ли версии CEF4 Chromium для Delphi 7 совместимые с Windows XP?

Tags: delphi-7, windows-xp, chromium

Интегрирую CEF3 (chromium) в Delphi в общем то успешно и статьи по этому поводу есть. Тем не менее хотелось бы понимать может быть есть версии CEF4 которые были бы совместимы с Windows XP (вроде как их и не было)? Если да то какие и где взять нужную старую версию?

*Возможно будет вопрос, что я забыл в Windows XP. Дело в том что chromium используется ботом, который используется на виртуальных машинах. XP меньше ресурсов едят, поэтому и целесообразнее под виртуалку.*